# Implementing C# Android Touch Input Resistance or Timeout - Unity

Tags: c#, android, input, unity-game-engine, touch

Good day,

I'm trying to make a tapping game, however, the amount of outputs that results from one touch is continuous.

How do I make one output per tap instead of....100?

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1 && idle == true) 
{
p = true; 
pSound.Play(); 
Debug.Log("Tap"); 
} 
else if (Input.touchCount == 0) 
{ 
p = false; 
}
```

Comment: Learn how to ask question properly. Why put your code in the comment section?

Comment: Fixed the question (b)

Comment: Now that you moved the code from the comment section to the question section, can you explain your question more? Rephrase it and explain what you want to be doing and what it is currently doing. And maybe include where you are running the code from, Start or Update function. Put a complete code required to replicate the problem.

Comment: So, if I run the code using unity remote on my android, the console prints 4 "Taps" when I quickly touch my screen. I'd like it to recognize the tap only after the finger is lifted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what `Input.touchCount` is for. `Touch.tapCount` is what used to detect taps. You need to get all touches from `Input.touches` and then save it to `Touch` struct as an array. Then loop over each touch and check which one has the ended `event` called. There you can check for `Touch.tapCount`.

```
void Update()
{
    Touch[] touchScreen = Input.touches;
    int touchScreenSize = touchScreen.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < touchScreenSize; i++)
    {
        if (touchScreen[i].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (touchScreen[i].tapCount == 1)
            {
                pSound.Play();
                Debug.Log("Tap");
            }
            else if (touchScreen[i].tapCount == 0)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, so with this I can check if I have more than one tap. However, because it doesn't restart after each tap, p = true is consistent. Would I need to reset the array after each touch in that if statement?

Comment: @itsPav Your problem is at `idle == true`. I don't know how that works and I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish there. I removed it and updated the code.It should work and you don't need to reset anything. Copy the new code.

Comment: That code is missing p = true, which unfortunately does not turn off even after I finished the tap. I've added it into my script, same problem. There's a public bool that checks for p, and what I have successfully done it using buttons, which turns it off after lifting finger from button, but this tap on screen is difficult.

Comment: @itsPav Your original problem was that the touch is being detected too many times per frame. Lets say 20 times. The code in my answer fixes that. It detects the tap only once (when finger is lifted). Check the debug.Log and you will see. What you described in your question is what I solved here. Whatever else you are trying to do , I don't know...

Comment: @itsPav and it would be good if you learn how to name variables. p? that doesn't describe anything. This problem is solved. You can create another new question and describe the new problem you are having. I might help if I understand your new problem.

Comment: That's true. Thanks.